# I have a table, but now i can't compare the value and replace it on the correct matrix placement

Tags: c, matrix, compare

im doing a program that has a matrix which is initialized by the numbers of the rows and dots where(which is where the field is).

So the beginning state should be:

```
5:......
4:......
3:......
2:......
1:......
  abcdef
```

The grid spaces are :

```
                     {"a5", "b5", "c5", "d5", "e5", "f5"},
                     {"a4", "b4", "c4", "d4", "e4", "f4"},
                     {"a3", "b3", "c3", "d3", "e3", "f3"},
                     {"a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2"},
                     {"a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1"}.
```

And if for example i input a5, the output should be:

```
5:X.....
4:......
3:......
2:......
1:......
  abcdef
```

My current code is this:

```
int main ()
{
    //definir tabuleiro
  int linhas = 5;
  int colunas = 6;
  char tabuleiro [linhas][colunas];
  char input [80];
  // Definir as posições do tabuleiro
  char coordenadacolaux;
  char coordenadalinaux;
  int coordenadalin ;
  int coordenadacol ;
  printf("%d is col, %d is ln\n", coordenadacol, coordenadalin);
    //Preencher o tabuleiro com '.'
  memset(tabuleiro, '.', sizeof tabuleiro);
  scanf("%s",input);
  coordenadacolaux = input[0];
  coordenadalinaux = input[1];
  printf("%d is col, %d is ln\n", coordenadacol, coordenadalin);
  switch (coordenadacolaux)
 {
    case 'a':
      coordenadacol = 0;
      printf("In a \n");
      printf("a is %d \n",coordenadacol);
      break;

    case 'b':
      coordenadacol = 1;
      printf("In b\n");
      printf("b is %d \n",coordenadacol);
      break;
      
    case 'c':
      coordenadacol = 2;
      printf("In c\n");
      printf("c is %d \n",coordenadacol);
      break;
    
    case 'd':
      coordenadacol = 3;
      printf("In d\n");
      printf("d is %d \n",coordenadacol);
      break;
    
    case 'e':
      coordenadacol = 4;
      printf("In e\n");
      printf("e is %d \n",coordenadacol);
      break;
    default: 
    printf("Casa invalida.");
}
    //cast = tranformar char em int
    coordenadalin = (int) coordenadalinaux;
    printf("%c is col, %c is ln\n", coordenadacol, coordenadalin);
   tabuleiro[coordenadacol][coordenadalin] = 'X';
  for(int count=5, i=0; i<linhas; i++, count--)
  {
      
    printf("%d:", count) ; 
    for(int j=0; j<colunas; j++)
    {
      printf("%c", tabuleiro[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("  abcdef");
}
```

But i'm stuck and can't seem to find where should i start, does what i did allow me to continue what i want to do?
The biggest question for me is, how do i compare the input string with the array space i want to replace?

Best Regards
Alegor

Comment: You do: `scanf("%s",input);` That is incorrect because `input` is an `int`. Compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall`) and this would be flagged by the compiler. Then, you never actually _use_ `input` for anything. I assume you want `input` to contain a grid reference (e.g. `a5`). So, you want: `char input[100];`

Comment: After fixing the above, you might want: `int colcur = input[0] - 'a'; int rowcur = input[1] - '0'; rowcur = linhas - rowcur; tabuleiro[rowcur][colcur] = 'X';` (i.e. I'm not sure if the separate character array is needed to decode the coordinates). Note that you should check `input[0]` to be in the range `'a'-'f'` and that `input[1]` is in the range: `'1'-'5'` before actually indexing into the array.

Comment: I used some of your tips, and used a switch for the first letter, but somehow the value stored in the "case" disappears when it leaves the switch function.